# Curious when putting an array into a column of a data frame

Tags: python, scikit-learn

```
import pandas as pd
df=pd.read_csv("")
df.head()
```

[image]

```
a=enc.fit_transform(df)
print(a)
print(type(a))
print(a.shape)
df["Gender"]=a
```

[image]

When the above code is executed, not only Gender but also Height and Weight are encoded and an ndarray of (10000,3) is created.

And I put it in the `df["Gender"]` column, but why did only the value of the 0th column of the a array go into the Gender column?

Where did the 1st and 2nd columns go?
(9.778e+03 9.982e+03...)

I think 1000*3 should have been entered in the Gender column.

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: What scikit-learn encoder are you using?